# Creating Structs That Match JSON Content in Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, parsing, struct

I am new to Swift, and have been trying to parse JSON from an API call. I have the parse part down, and I have made structs that relate to the JSON data :

```
    struct Result: Codable {
        let data: [PeopleData]
    }
    struct PeopleData: Codable {
        let name: String
        let address: String
        let friends: [String]
```

However, I am not sure if this is the correct format. Here is the JSON :

```
{
  "data": [
  {
   "name": "Mike",
   "address": "72 Highway Boulevard",
   "friends": [
  {
   "name": "Joe",
   "address": "1234 Rainbow Road"
  },
  {
   "name": "Andy",
   "address": "885 Street Road
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

I cannot change the JSON format, so how would I create structs that adhere to the format of JSON? I understand that [] is an array, and {} is an object in JSON, so I am just trying to sort this out. Thanks in advance

Comment: try www.quicktype.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`friends` is not a String array, it should also be a Struct:

```
struct Result: Codable {
    let data: [PeopleData]
}
struct FriendData: Codable {
    let name: String
    let address: String
}
struct PeopleData: Codable {
    let name: String
    let address: String
    let friends: [FriendData]
}
```

should work.

**Nitpick:** If you do not need to encode those back, `Decodable` should be enough instead of `Codable`.

**P.S:** [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/)  is also a great tool for this.

Comment: any way to do exactly what quickType dose , directly   in swift  ?